# Center vertically and horizontally while obeying html rules with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make something similar to Bootstraps [jumbotron](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron) class using flexbox.  I want everything to be centered vertically and horizontally, but I want anything inside of the box to still respect standard HTML rules.  That is, if I make an `<h1>` and then an `<h4>` I want them to be on separate lines; however, with my current flexbox properties, that's not happening.  See the example below -- it looks like `titlesubtitle` instead of `title\nsubtitle`

```css
.Jumbotron {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="Jumbotron">
  <h1>title</h1>
  <h4>subtitle</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, that will not work with existing markup since `flexbox` treat block and inline elements the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce a new, non-flex parent to wrap those elements, so that parent will be the centered flex-child, and it's children will just be normal, non-flex children

```css
.Jumbotron {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="Jumbotron">
  <div>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <h4>subtitle</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or for your example, if you just want the children of the flex parent to be on their own line, use  `flex-direction: column;`

```css
.Jumbotron {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="Jumbotron">
  <h1>title</h1>
  <h4>subtitle</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the first sample since that is wrong if 2 span where direct child of flex parent, they would behave as a block (each on its own line), which they aren't